# BlackBerry Create a table with four clickable image rows

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-jde

How to create BlackBerry Table model with four clickable image rows (6.0.0 java) ? . I found [this](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Using-TableModel-TableView-TableController-and-DataTemplate-to/ta-p/617305)
post but I'm very new to blackberry development so I have no idea to create the simple table. Please help me to do this.
I want to create something like this.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: use gridfield manager

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Please point me to simple code example. I'm just two days with BlackBerry

Comment: http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/11958/Create_grid_layout_877557_11.jsp